# Get model's type in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-controller

Is there any way to get a type of `model` without accessing to the parameters?

My controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeViewModel model)
{
   SomeMethod(/* How to pass models's type here? */)
}

private void SomeMethod(Type type)
{
  // come code
}
```

Method `SomeMethod(Type type)` will be called in many other actions. And

```
Type modelType = typeof(SomeViewModel);
or
Type modelType = model.GetType();
```

are not suitable.

Comment: to use a model in a view you have to define the type of model at the top.  I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish here

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add the post attribute.

Comment: again,  your model is defined here.  the only way I can think of to send multiple models to an action would be define them (SomeViewModel model, SomeViewModel2 model2, etc.  at which point you could do a null check to see which one was passed

Comment: Why do you want to do this - sounds odd?

Comment: I'm trying to create one abstract mechanism. That needs to know about the type of model. And obviously - `Type modelType = typeof(SomeViewModel);` or `Type modelType = model.GetType();` are not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about in context of View? If yes then you can create strongly typed View using one of ViewModel class. Then you will have the type of that model in View. The topmost line in View.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding with a model and what the form submits to the server. 
In most cases the model has several infos about the page, like title, description, userprofile and so on.
When you push submit on a form you send to the action only the fields included in the form. It means that most data are not available in that action and you have to create it manually

Take a look to that code:

```
<h1>@Model.ArticleTitle</h1>
<p>@Model.ArticleDescription</p>
<form method="post">

@Html.EditFor(x=> x.CommentTitle)
@Html.EditFor(x=> x.CommentBody)

</form>
```

In that case the browser sends to the server only the CommentTitle and the CommentBody. ArticleTitle and ArticleDescription are not sent.

.u